# Incrementar una lista en Python con un For

Tags: python, arraylist

Como será posible incrementar un arreglo de este tipo,
1.-Lee los datos dependiendo que tenga 1 2 3 4 ... n llene la variable opciones mediante el ciclo for, sin la necesidad de un if y realizar la lista uno mismo.

```
if len(datos)==1:
 opciones=[["1"]] 
elif len(datos)==2:
  opciones=[["1"],["2"]]
elif len(datos)==3:
  opciones=[["1"],["2"],["3"]]
...
elif len(datos)==n:
  opciones=[["1"],["2"],["3"]...["n"]]
```

Comment: `opciones = [[str(i + 1)] for i in range(len(datos))]`

Comment: Muchas gracias Candid Moe